# BIGINT Out-of-range Error since MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, nested-sets, outofrangeexception

I'm working with nested sets for my CMS but since MySQL 5.5 I can't move a node.
The following error gets thrown:

Error while reordering docs:Error in MySQL-DB: Invalid SQL:

```
 SELECT baum2.id AS id,
 COUNT(*) AS level
 FROM elisabeth_tree AS baum1,
 elisabeth_tree AS baum2
 WHERE baum2.lft BETWEEN baum1.lft AND baum1.rgt
 GROUP BY baum2.lft
 ORDER BY ABS(baum2.id - 6);
```

error: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(`lektoren`.`baum2`.`id` - 6)'
 error number: 1690

Has anyone solved this Problem? I already tried to cast some parts but it wasn't successful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

BIGINT UNSIGNED is unsigned and cannot be negative.

Your expression `ABS(lektoren.baum2.id - 6)` will use a negative intermediate value if id is less than 6.

Presumably earlier versions implicitly converted to SIGNED. You need to do a cast.

Try

```
ORDER BY ABS(CAST(lectoren.baum2.id AS SIGNED) - 6)
```

Comment: According to [the docs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_unsigned_subtraction): _By default, subtraction between integer operands produces an UNSIGNED result if any operand is UNSIGNED._

Comment: I have also faced the same problem after upgrading to Mysql5.5 See here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html

Comment: `CAST(x AS BIGINT SIGNED`) throws an error. According to [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast), only `SIGNED` should be used (or `SIGNED INTEGER`). I edited answer according to that.

Answer (score 5):

```
SET sql_mode = 'NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION';
```

Call this before the query is executed.

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY ABS(CAST(lectoren.baum2.id AS BIGINT SIGNED) - 6)`

That change would be mysql only.

instead, do

```
ORDER BY ABS(- 6 + baum2.id);
```