# MySQL BIGINT UNSINGED value is out or range while multiplying with (-1)

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BIGINT Out-of-range Error since MySQL 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743069/bigint-out-of-range-error-since-mysql-5-5)

Anyone has any ideas why the following produces a 1690 error: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out or range?

```
SELECT CAST(IF(trades.`buyer` = 63, -1, 1)  * trades.`price` * trades.`amount` AS SIGNED) AS priceTotal 
FROM trades
WHERE (trades.`buyer` = 63 OR trades.`seller`= 63);
```

What I'm trying to do is make the priceTotal negative when the user is the buyer.

Comment: Error Code: 1690
BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(if((`trades`.`buyer` = 63),-(1),1) * `trades`.`price`)'

Comment: Even though [this doc page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_unsigned_subtraction) is talking about subtraction, I imagine the same principle applies. _By default, subtraction between integer operands produces an UNSIGNED result if any operand is UNSIGNED._

Comment: Also, same conclusion found in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743069/bigint-out-of-range-error-since-mysql-5-5).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unsigned values have to be zero or more - so `-1` is out of range.  Don't use unsigned maybe?

From the [data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html#idm140308345229888) docs:

> `BIGINT[(M)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]`
>
> A large integer. The signed range is `-9223372036854775808` to
>   `9223372036854775807`. The unsigned range is `0` to `18446744073709551615`.

Or cast each value to signed when using it in a mixed-sign context, something like this maybe:

```
IF(trades.`buyer` = 63, -1, 1) * CAST(trades.`price` AS SIGNED) * CAST(trades.`amount` AS SIGNED)
```

Comment: you mean the `price` and `amount` cols need to be signed?

Comment: @JohnKrommidas - if you want to store a negative value in there they would need to be signed, yes.

Comment: I just want it to be displayed negative in the result set. I'm not storing any negative values in my database.

Comment: The `price` and `amount` columns are of type UNSIGNED SMALLINT(5)

Comment: There is a typo (SGINED) in the code. Can't fix it myself since the edit is < 6 characters.