# BIGINT overflow error in mysql for XOR

Tags: mysql, sql, bigint

Can someone explain why Mysql runs into BIGINT overflow when below sql is executed

```
select 100-0^222;

ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in  '(100 - (0 ^ 222))'
```

But runs fine with

```
select 0^222;
```

Comment: Runs perfect in my management studio.

Comment: Runs perfect too with result 186 on management studio!

Comment: I can confirm also that the first statement does not produce an error.  I get result: 18446744073709551494.  This is from MySQL Workbench.

Comment: talking about Mysql server?

Comment: i am run it on mysql server and get error

Comment: The version of MySQL being run might be important to provide, as that could explain why some get the error and some do not.

Comment: I am running it on with Mysql cli (server 5.5.20-log) on Windows 64 bit.

Comment: my version is 5.5.40 debian, and i got error

Comment: error goes from  select 100 - 0 ^ 101;

Comment: nice finding Andrey :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743069/bigint-out-of-range-error-since-mysql-5-5?rq=1

Comment: The different behavior is because automatic casting from unsigned to signed is [optional](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_unsigned_subtraction).

Comment: See [12.12 Bit Functions :: Bitwise XOR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-xor): `The result is an unsigned 64-bit integer.`. Try: `SELECT 100-CAST(0^222 AS SIGNED);`

Comment: `unsigned` = default, non negative numbers. That's why. Cast it to `signed`. Error tells you exactly what's wrong..